# iPhone browser scroll faster - webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch with positon:fixed do not work - alternatives with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

I've spent the entire day and a bit of yesterday trying to get faster scrolling on the iPhone which is **terribly slow by default**.

I've tried to add:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

to the element which does enable faster/ideal scrolling, but it makes elements such as the top and bottom menu which are **positioned fixed** to disappear.

There are numerous suggestions online on how to deal with this, but they all fail.

Among these was to set, which does show the elements:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

However, it basically turns positon:fixed into position:absolute or static, which is not the desired effect.

I have started to think that the only way to solve this would be through  Javascript but it's not easy to get it to work properly.

I have written this piece, but it doesn't work 100%. Maybe you can help figure it out? It's still a bit to go. Speed would need to be animated, but if I can get this first piece to work, then that can be dealt with.

Look for **bindScroll** call at the bottom:

```
(function() {

    // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
    // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
    var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

    function preventDefault(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
    }

    function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
        if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function disableScroll() {
        if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
            window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
        window.onwheel      = preventDefault; // modern standard
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
        window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
        document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
    }

    function enableScroll() {
        if (window.removeEventListener)
            window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;
        window.onwheel      = null;
        window.ontouchmove  = null;
        document.onkeydown  = null;
    }

    function bindScroll(element, speed) {

        var disabled  = false;
        var last      = 0;
        var to        = 0;

        element.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {

            if ( !disabled ) {
                disabled = true; disableScroll();

                var direction = 1;
                if ( element.scrollTop < last ) {
                    direction = -1;
                }

                last = (element.scrollTop += speed*direction);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    if ( element.scrollTop >= last ) {
                        disabled = false; enableScroll();
                    }
                }, 1);

            }

            return false;
        });

    }

    bindScroll($('.p').get(0), 100);

})();
```

**Is there other solutions which does not break stuff out there?**